# "The intersection of a plane with a right circular cylinder could be which of the following?"

Tags: geometry

Could it be intersecting lines?

Could you provide me with a drawing demonstrating that "it is impossible for the intersection of a plane and cylinder to form intersecting lines because there is no intersecting lines on a cylinder".

From Barron's SAT Subject Test Math Level 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only lines on a right circular cylinder are the vertical rulings, and they are all parallel.

Comment: If one draws a plane at a 45 degree angle through the cylinder, can't one get intersecting lines? I.E. the lines in the plane will intersect with the two horizontal rulings.

Comment: You get an ellipse in this case

Comment: do ellipses consist of intersecting lines?

Comment: @AmandaKelius What do you know about the shape of an ellipse? (hint: it's bounded, unlike lines)